# regex to get matching text between multiple patterns with javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Let's say i have the following string :

```
KEYWORD_1 OR "KEYWORD COMPOSITE_2" NOT "KEYWORD COMPOSITE_3" NOT "KEYWORD_4" AND "KEYWORD_5" KEYWORD_6 KEYWORD_7 KEYWORD_8 -KEYWORD_9
```

The result (this is not JSON format, just a visual formatting to explain the output) i want to get with my regex(es) is to split the string to the following three arrays of keywords, each one is corresponding to a delimiter (AND, OR, NOT) and contains all the words that follows every occurrence of the delimiter. 
Think of it like the google search field syntaxt :) :

```
final_result = {
    {
        OR: [KEYWORD_COMPOSITE_2]
    },
    {
        AND: [
            KEYWORD_1, 
            KEYWORD_5, 
            KEYWORD_6, 
            KEYWORD_7, 
            KEYWORD_8
        ]
    },
    {
        NOT: [
            KEYWORD_COMPOSITE_3, 
            KEYWORD_4, 
            KEYWORD_9
        ]
    }
}
```

I am trying to do this in javascript with one or more regex.

Any idea ? any help ?
thank you

Comment: This is not a good job for a regex.

Comment: Well, where do you need help? What exactly is not working for you ?

Comment: Why is there a - in front of KEYWORD_9

Comment: Are you sure that your provided the expected output?

Comment: `AND: [
            KEYWORD_1,` JSON is correct? It does not make sense if you take into consideration that your String is an "IF". Could make this clearer, how exactly do you need this to work? (edit your question and explain better how this should work, thanks)

Comment: @TimPietzcker : well, i tried making this with multiple slit, and this drives to multiple nested loops and a relatively complicated code to maintain...

Comment: @CrazyTrain : please see comment above,  so i wanned to try a regex !
The problem is, i can't find one regex the does this, or even makes me close it the result. so i am looking for some help.

Comment: @epascarello : because it's another delimiter yet. but if you want to simplify, consider it as a NOT.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento : i edit the post and added some explanation :)

Comment: @AlexFilipovici : yes, this is the output i want.

Comment: `AND: [ KEYWORD_1,` JSON is correct? its String equivalent to a FORK? Diretio I still do not understand how it should work (I know what you need, the problem is your String has no logic in JSON format, the problem is to understand the logic)

Comment: Actually the first "Keyword" will always be "AND"?

Comment: As you i said, it's not JSON format, it's just a visual formatting to say i want 3 arrays/objects corresponding to my 3 delimiters (AND,OR,NOT) with de corresponding keywords. the logic is the same with the syntaxt of google search

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento : Yes ! the first word will always be in "AND"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that with regexes alone, some programming is still required:

```
function parse(input) {
    var keywords = ['AND', 'OR', 'NOT'];
    var result = {}, kw = 'AND';
    input.replace(/"(.+?)"|(\w+)/g, function($0, $1, $2) {
        if(keywords.indexOf($2) >= 0) {
            kw = $2;
        } else {
            if(!(kw in result))
                result[kw] = [];
            result[kw].push($1 || $2);
        }
    });
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Do not use `(.+?)` Has other better ways.

Comment: Well this is pretty nice and close to what i want but sill don't make it :)

It gives me a great starting ! i think i can improve it ;)

Comment: @WissemGarouachi: glad to hear it was helpful - edited to meet your specs more closely.

Comment: @thg435 replace `"(.+?)"` by `["][^"]+["]`, eg.: `/["][^"]+["]|(\w+)/g`

Comment: Thank you this is useful, sorry i don't have enough reputation to upvote your answer :)

i have one last question : you think i can't split on the 3 delimiters in the same time the loop on the result by couple of matches and not one by one ? this way i will have in each iteration a couple (matched_keyword, delimiter).
something like this : (\sOR\s)|(\sAND\s)|(\sNOT\s)
but this looks ugly :p

Comment: @WissemGarouachi: I'm not sure I understand... You cannot just split by `AND|OR|NOT`, because any keyword can (theoretically) occur within quotes, for example `AND "FOO OR BAR" "NOT BAZ"`.